# Ubuntu hangs after grub while installation

Tags: boot, grub2

my computer was working fine.

I installed unetbooting and I wanted to installed windows 7 to my usb .

So I opened unetboot and my USB was formated to fat 32 and selected the windows 7 `iso` with my USB.

Then I restarted my laptop with the USB plunged in. unetboot showed up but there was no `iso` to select so I just switched off my computer by holding the hardware boot button. and then restarted my computer. grub loaded and allowed me to make my selection but when I clicked Ubuntu it would stay on the black terminal thing and won't boot.

I tried the recovery but that won't load either. My Windows Vista loads up fine but Ubuntu doesn't

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) should allow you to solve this problem, there are several ways to run it, but I suggest you to install it on Try mode of your Ubuntu Live .iso